# Spring Boot (inject script in reactjs)

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm having a really difficult time figuring out what I possibly could do wrong as probably most scenarios has been tested.

I'm writing web app using *Spring Boot* and *ReactJS* for frontend. I'm trying for now to write simple script showing some plain text which is imported from separate file to html one. After doing so, I ended up with nothing really showing up.

Here is my structure of project:

[image]

and here is my **app.js** in which I have my component defined:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="commentBox">
            Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
        </div>
    );
}
});
   ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Below is the **cardists.html** page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cardists</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
    3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

   <div id='root'></div>
      <script src="react-15.0.1.js"></script>
      <script src="react-dom-15.0.1.js"></script>
      <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-
       core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/babel" src="../public/js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**[PROBLEM]**
Where could I possibly made a mistake as everything for first glance seems ok to me, but I'm getting blank page ;/

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering your application in `content` div like

```
ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById('content')
```

But in you html file there is no div with `content` id. There is one div with id `root` so you need to render your component in that div like

```
ReactDOM.render(<CommentBox />, document.getElementById('root')
```